# Run React Native in window

Tags: node.js, react-native, android-jetifier

I am a newbie in react native and recently I've started to install it but in one step I have a problem :

```
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
```

unfortunately, it takes too long and seems doesn't work at all.
what is the problem ??

Answer (score 0):

React native needs to bundle all of your files, that’s why it takes so long to run.
Jetify is just a tool used to convert all your android library dependency’s to androidX. I believe it’s included automatically in the latest releases of react native. 
You can manually remove jetify from your package.json under “post install” if you believe that is causing your issue.